# Stop inherited method from running from inside it's super method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have these two classes:

```py
class A():
  def foo():
    print("foo inside A!")

class B(A):
  def foo():
    super().foo()
    print("foo inside B!")

x = B()
x.foo()
```

This will print:

```
foo inside A!
foo inside B!
```

Is there a clean way I can abort the execution of the code in `B`'s `foo` method from `A`'s `foo` method?

Something like:

```py
class A():
  def foo():
    print("foo inside A!")
    if some condition:
      <return from inherited method here>

class B(A):
  def foo():
    super().foo()
    print("foo inside B!")

x = B()
x.foo()
```

so that the output will be:

```
foo inside A!
```

Edit: just to clarify, I'm trying to avoid checking the return of `super().foo()` in `B`'s `foo` method.

Comment: Move the `if some condition:` in `B.foo`.

Comment: is removing the definition of `B.foo` an option, i.e.,  simply relying on inheriting `foo` from `A`?

Comment: @CristiFati I'm trying to avoid that as there are multiple classes that inherit from `A` and I want to avoid repeating code in all the classes.

Comment: @jeschwar This is the best option. It sounds like inheritance isn't the best idea in this situation.

Comment: @jeschwar no, it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could raise an exception from `A.foo()` which you catch in `B.foo()` and do some work in the `except` clause. Maybe like this:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("foo inside A!")

        if 'some condition':
            raise MyException

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        try:
            super().foo()
        except MyException:
            print("foo inside B!")
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: You could even create your custom `Exception` subclass to catch only that particular type of exceptions in `B.foo()`; I added that to my answer

Comment: That might be my plan B if nobody else comes up with something else!

Comment: I think using exceptions for this looks rather clean.

Comment: @alexandernst raising exceptions is a pretty clean construct and is quite Pythonic

Comment: @alexandernst if this solution does not work for you then I think you need to re-evaluate the structure of your classes

Answer (score 1):

Your `A.foo()` method could return a value which you check in `B.foo()`. Maybe like this:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("foo inside A!")
        if 'some condition':
            return True
        else:
            return False

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        val = super().foo()

        if val:
            print("foo inside B!")
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid checking the return value of `super().foo()` in `B` as there are multiple classes inheriting from A and I'd like to avoid having to duplicate that check in all classes.

Comment: @alexandernst,  after thinking for a while, there is also merit in this answer, because given your restriction, you actually have less code to write here, specially if you change all your classes to an `if super().foo():` protection block, instead of the `try except block`. Exceptions are suited for this kind of problem, but specifically here this is straightforward too.